# Rails 3 content_for issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've recently built a fairly deep nested form using     http:// github.com/timriley/complex-form-examples for guidance. The form partial uses the following in order to render new fields when a link is clicked:

```
<%= yield :warehouses_fields_template %>
<%= yield :ratgrades_fields_template %>
```

The content for these is generated in the ApplicationHelper as such:

```
def new_child_fields_template(form_builder, association, options = {})
    content_for "#{association}_fields_template" do
      options[:object] ||= form_builder.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
      options[:partial] ||= association.to_s.singularize
      options[:form_builder_local] ||= :f

      content_tag(:div, :id => "#{association}_fields_template", :style => "display: none") do
        form_builder.fields_for(association, options[:object], :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |f|
          render(:partial => options[:partial], :locals => {options[:form_builder_local] => f})
        end
      end
    end unless content_given?("#{association}_fields_template")
end

def content_given?(name)
    content = instance_variable_get("@content_for_#{name}")
    ! content.nil?
end
```

Everything seemed to be working perfectly on rails 2.3.8, but after upgrading to Rails 3 rc today the templates are no longer loaded. Has something changed that would make the above code invalid? Anyone else noticing the same problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

For reference, this is the relevant jQuery code as well:

```
$(function() {
  $('form a.add_child').live('click', function() {
    // Setup
    var assoc   = $(this).attr('data-association');           // Name of child
    var content = $('#' + assoc + '_fields_template').html(); // Fields template

    // Make the context correct by replacing new_<parents> with the generated ID
    // of each of the parent objects
    var context = ($(this).parents('.fields').children('input:first').attr('name') || '').replace(new RegExp('\[[a-z]+\]$'), '');

    // context will be something like this for a brand new form:
    // project[tasks_attributes][1255929127459][assignments_attributes][1255929128105]
    // or for an edit form:
    // project[tasks_attributes][0][assignments_attributes][1]
    if(context) {
      var parent_names = context.match(/[a-z]+_attributes/g) || []
      var parent_ids   = context.match(/[0-9]+/g)

      for(i = 0; i < parent_names.length; i++) {
        if(parent_ids[i]) {
          content = content.replace(
            new RegExp('(\\[' + parent_names[i] + '\\])\\[.+?\\]', 'g'),
            '$1[' + parent_ids[i] + ']'
          )
        }
      }
    }

    // Make a unique ID for the new child 
    var regexp  = new RegExp('new_' + assoc, 'g');
    var new_id  = new Date().getTime();
    content     = content.replace(regexp, new_id)

    $(this).parent().before(content);
    return false;
  });
});
```

I've included a Gist with some more of the relevant pages if it'll help:  http://gist.github.com/536704

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same issue. In rails 3 you now have to use symbols. So use:

```
content_for :"#{association}_fields_template" do
```

and

```
end unless content_for?(:"#{association}_fields_template")
```

(delete the useless `content_given?` method which is now the built-in `content_for?`).

Also use

```
<%= content_for :warehouses_fields_template %>
<%= content_for :ratgrades_fields_template %>
```

instead of

```
<%= yield :warehouses_fields_template %>
<%= yield :ratgrades_fields_template %>
```

Comment: thank you! resolved my issue as I was running into the same thing. thanks!!